# Numpy gives memory error while running a Python file

Tags: python, numpy

I'm trying to run a Python file, but every time it gives me this error. What could be the cause of this error and a possible solution? I'm using the latest version of numpy-1.17.0

```
numpy.core._exceptions.MemoryError: Unable to allocate array with shape 
(129941, 400, 16) and data type int32
```

Comment: Kindly provide the traceback and the code snippet that errors out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your array is too big. `int32` is 32 bits so 4 bytes and `4*129941*400*16 = 3326489600 bytes = 3.3264896 Gigabytes`.

Comment: what can be the possible solution?

Comment: use a smaller array @JaydeepBorkar

Comment: I freed up some space by killing unnecessary processes and it worked. Thanks for the help :)

Answer (score 0):

This is likely due to your system's `overcommit handling mode`.
In the default mode, `0`,
You can check it using

```
$ cat /proc/sys/vm/overcommit_memory
```

You have to set it `1`,using

```
$ echo 1 | sudo tee /proc/sys/vm/overcommit_memory
```